# create a list in c lisp recursively

Tags: list, recursion, common-lisp

I am trying to create a list in lisp that starts at n and ends at 2.

```
(setq liste ())


(defun makeList (n)
    (if (> n 2)
        (setq liste (append (makeList (- n 1)) liste)
        (setq liste (append liste 2))))
```

This doesn't seem to work. Anybody help?

Comment: also do I need to instantiate the list first, should I write ´defvar list ()` somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

`setq` only changes a variable. You need to define it first. If you rely on a global variable then the second time around your result will have the elements of the previous run. It's very smelly!

```
;; With recursion
(defun my-make-list (start)
  (if (< start 2)
      '()
      (cons start (my-make-list (1- start)))))

;; with tail recursion
(defun my-make-list (start)
  (labels ((helper (cur acc)
             (if (> cur start)
                 acc
                 (helper (1+ cur) (cons cur acc)))))
    (helper 2 '())))

;; With loop
(defun my-make-list (start)
  (loop :for n :from start :downto 2
        :collect n))
```

The last one is best since CL doesn't guarantee tail call optimization. Notice that I do the tail recursive one in reverse since all lists are made from end to beginning.